# Solr grouping issue

Tags: solr

Being new to Solr (3.6.1 used on the project that I am working on) I am trying to understand how logical grouping can limit the data returned.

Working with the test data and schema that is supplied as part of the solr download when I run a query like `id:1 and id:2` which based on the data returns 2 documents

but in the next case

```
(id:1 and popularity:0) and (id:2 and popularity:7)
```

I would assume that I would only get 1 document back as there is no document that has a popularity of 0 and yet all 5 documents are returned (I only loaded 5)

In the last case where I have `int1 and (id:2 and popularity:7)` I get three documents based on the tests i do (through the admin web page) and / or seem to return the same number of results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional research it turns out that the parser (atleast the one used for the admin window) so lowercase and will be treated as the default operator which is normally defined as OR so anded clauses must be upper cased AND not and for the correct results to be returned.